# What does a C++ class look like in assembly

Tags: assembly, c++

I am planning to do some reverse engineering on an application that was written in a object oriented way. And now I'm kind of curious what a C++ class would look like in assembly. I already found out the basics about functions and their calling conventions. But classes are probably way more complex, right?

So let's say we have this class:

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area() {return width*height;}
};

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}
```

and this object:

```
Rectangle rect;
rect.set_values (3,4);
```

What would/could it look like in assembly?

Comment: even for simple C code, the assembly output depends on compiler and compiler options. To see how the output is in various compilers, use [GCC Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Answer (score 8):

As discussed in https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/5957/1562, it's compiler-dependent (different compilers will generate different machine code and data structures).

However, you may want to refer to [Reversing C++](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-07/Sabanal_Yason/Paper/bh-dc-07-Sabanal_Yason-WP.pdf), as it does a pretty good job showing how most compilers compile C++ classes.

Comment: The reversing C++ paper is invaluable.

Comment: In the microsoft x64 convention where RCX, RDX, R8, R9 are used are arguments, is RCX still used by c++ for the this pointer ?